# Get Entity reference without primary key

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to update an entity. To to that I want reference(entityManager.getReference()) of below entity.

But I have only 'departmentId' and 'jobRole' and combination of that make unique column.

Ideally primary key is not required in this kind of table but it is present(legacy code).

Is there Any way so that I can get reference of entity using this two Id. They don't have any constrain like unique or composite etc.

```
@Entity
Class Employee {
 @Id
 private Integer id; // pk
 private Integer departmentId;
 private Integer jobRole;
... and many other fields 
}
```

```
    @Query("update Employee e set s.name=:name where e.jobRole=:jobRole and e.departmentId=:departmentId")
    int update(@Param("name") String name,
    @Param("jobRole") Integer jobRole,
    @Param("departmentId") Integer departmentId );
```

Basically want to achieve above query

```
Employee emp = entityManager.getReferance(Employee.class, (deptId, jobRole));
emp.setName("abc");
```

Comment: I would do it with JPA repository. Auto-generated method would be findByDepatmentIdJobRole(id,role)

Comment: @Mar-Z it is regarding
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-manager-get-reference

Comment: why are you looking to use getReference specifically instead of just querying for the entity on those two properties - why exactly do you need it? If departmentId and jobRole are a natural primary key for your entity, why don't you make that the entity's ID? Just because there is another unique ID field called id doesn't mean it has to be 'the' ID for the entity. JPA only requires what you use is unique so that it can reliably cache and track the entity's identity. You might want to ensure those field are indexed like the ID field in the table would be.